# print footer HTML to PDF iTextSharp PdfWriter

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I am using iTextSharp PDF library to convert plain html into multiple pages PDF file. the problem is with printing footer on every page. I have tried everything but nothing worked. please help me to sort out this issue. Below is my complete code:-

```
htmlTable.Append("<div style='position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:60px;background:#6cf;'>This is a footer. Page </div>");

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
               
                //htmlTable.Append("<div style='page-break-before: always'>");
              
                htmlTable.Append("<div style='font-weight:bold;text-align: center;'><u></u></div>");
               
               
                htmlTable.Append("<table border='1' width='80%'>");
                htmlTable.Append("<tr>");

              
                htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
                int k = 1;
                string qry1 = "select * from tb where No='" + NO + "' and Name='" + SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
              
                   
                htmlTable.Append("</table>");
                htmlTable.Append("<br/>");
                //
               
                //htmlTable.Append("<div style='text-align: right;'>(" + name + ")</div>");
                htmlTable.Append("<table border='0' float='right'>");
                htmlTable.Append("<tr>");
                htmlTable.Append("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
                htmlTable.Append("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
                htmlTable.Append("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
                htmlTable.Append("<td>(" + name + ")</td>");
                htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
                htmlTable.Append("</table>");
               // htmlTable.Append("<br/>");
                //htmlTable.Append("<div style='width:20%;text-align: right;'>(" + address + ")</div>");
                htmlTable.Append("<table border='0' float='right'>");
                htmlTable.Append("<tr>");
                htmlTable.Append("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
                htmlTable.Append("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
                htmlTable.Append("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
                htmlTable.Append("<td colspan='2'>R/o " + address + "</td>");
                htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
                htmlTable.Append("</table>");
                //htmlTable.Append("<div style='position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:60px;background:#6cf;'>This is a footer. Page </div>");
                //htmlTable.Append("<br/><br/><br/><br/>");
                //htmlTable.Append("<div style=\"font-family: \'Arial\', sans-serif; color: #ccc; font-size: 10px; margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;bottom:0;position:fixed;\">Simple page footer aligned by center.</div>");
                
              
                //htmlTable.Append("<div style='page-break-after:always;'>&nbsp;</div>");
              
                htmlTable.Append("<newpage />");
            }
            lblResult.Text = htmlTable.ToString();

            //Creating the object of the String Writer.
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            // Creating the object of HTML Writer and passing the object of String Writer to HTMl Text Writer
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            //this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
            lblResult.RenderControl(hw);
            // Now we what ever is rendered on the page we will give it to the object of the String reader so that we can 
            StringReader srdr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

            // Creating the PDF DOCUMENT using the Document class from Itextsharp.pdf namespace
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50F, 50F, 50F, 0.2F);

            // HTML Worker allows us to parse the HTML Content to the PDF Document.To do this we will pass the object of Document class as a Parameter.

            //  HTMLWorker hparse = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

            HTMLWorkerExtended hparse = new HTMLWorkerExtended(pdfDoc);
            //using (var htmlWorker = new HTMLWorkerExtended()
            //{
            //    htmlWorker.Open();
            //    htmlWorker.Parse(htmlViewReader);
            //}

            // Finally we write data to PDF and open the Document
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();

            // Now we will pass the entire content that is stored in String reader to HTML Worker object to achieve the data from to String to HTML and then to PDF.
            hparse.Parse(srdr);

            pdfDoc.Close();

            //Now finally we write to the PDF Document using the Response.Write method.
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; // Setting the application
                                                      // Assigning the header
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
        }

public class HTMLWorkerExtended : HTMLWorker
```

{
public HTMLWorkerExtended(Document document) : base(document)
{

```
}
public override void StartElement(string tag, Hashtable h)
{
    if (tag.Equals("newpage"))
        document.Add(Chunk.NEXTPAGE);
    else
        base.StartElement(tag, h);
}
```

}